# Change a sign against the function sum

Tags: r

I begin with R and I want to know how to change a sign & in all my data by the function sum. For example:

```
200&3 in 200+3.
```

I did this:

```
bree<-as.data.frame(sapply(bree, function(x) gsub("&", "+", x)))
```

But I think it just change the sign but R does not the "meaning" of +

Comment: can you please give us a reproducible example?  Is `bree` a vector of type character, i.e. `bree = c("200&3","100&2","12")` ?  Would the output be a numeric vector `c(203,102,12)` ?

Comment: bree is my data, so I need to change all & in my data by the function "sum". Yes your example is correct. How can I do this?

Comment: I understand that R read the new "+" as a sign and not as the function sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hacky possibility  (there may not be any *non*-hacky solutions):

```
atplusfun <- function(x) eval(parse(text=gsub("&","+",x)))
sapply(bree, atplusfun)
```

(this results in a numeric vector: you can make it into a data frame or whatever thereafter)

Comment: I thought eval was going to work in here, but couldn't get it going! I like your solution much more than my own.

Comment: if this answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 1):

This is really hacky, but it solves your toy problem. It will need some modification to be generalizable:

```
df = data.frame(group = c("200&3","200&5","1200&3","200&6"))

bree<- data.frame("group"=apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  split_dat <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "&")))
  '+'(split_dat[1], split_dat[2])
  }))
```

Comment: It works for 1 cell but I have 100000 observations.. I want to do this just for 1 column but even if that it does not work.